# RestKit - Automatic entity mapping

Tags: objective-c, restkit-0.20

I'm trying to use RestKit to perform automatic mapping of any given entity class name, without having to define the fields manually.

Example, imagine a managed object called `Product` with fields: `id`, `name`, `type`. This entity is on the default store.

I need to get the list of products from this URL `http://machin.net/products`

```
RKEntityMapping *map = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Product"
    inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];
```

**Question 1** `defaultStore` is not satisfying the required store, I don't even know how to specify it.

```
[map addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"id": @"id",
    @"name": @"name",
    @"type": @"type",
}];
```

**Question 2** As you can see, I'm using all the fields and they are the same on source & destination, I didn't find any way to tell RestKit to simply use all the fields of the given class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1. you need to configure your RestKit / Core Data stack

```
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
    RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];

    self.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;

    [RKManagedObjectStore setDefaultStore:managedObjectStore];

    // complete the core data stack setup
    [managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];
```

For 2. you can use

```
[map addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[
@"id",
@"name",
@"type",
];
```

Technically you could use some introspection on the entity but you'd write a lot more code.

Comment: Thank you for your help. You are talking about introspection for getting the list of fields ? You mean RK don't manage this introspection ?

Comment: RK introspects the destination entity / object keys so it knows what's possible. But that is deep in the mapping processing logic and not available to you when defining the mapping (which is intended just to list the keys you want and the relationship between the keys in your model and the keys in the source data).

Comment: I see, it doesn't seem to me like an exotic need, is it ? I mean it would be useful to be able to consider all the fields then eventually add some exceptions to the mapping...

Answer (score 5):

About **Question 2**

I found a simple way to automatically map the entity by using [`RKPropertyIntrospector`](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKPropertyInspector.html)

```
NSEntityDescription *entity =
    [[managedObjectModel entitiesByName] objectForKey:@"Product"];
[map addAttributeMappingsFromArray:[[[RKPropertyInspector sharedInspector]
    propertyInspectionForEntity:entity] allKeys]];
```

We can even add exceptions by using `@{} keysOfEntriesPassingTest`